# Php - Force Download xml file, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, dom

I read  about force download from CodeIgniter tutorials,

```
$data = 'Here is some text!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';

force_download($name, $data);
```

instead of `$data` is it possible to use DOM OBJECT `$dom = xml_dom();`

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$name = 'import.xml';
force_download($name,$dom);
```

When I Do this, it downloads the xml file (import.xml) with errors.

This page contains the following errors:

> error on line 27 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>       Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I cannot Convert `DOMObject` to `String`, But is there a way to change Download Helper in my system Folder so that it download the xml file.

Thank you

Comment: you need to pass some xml data in $dom variable something like '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document><yourtag>sqs</yourtag></Document>'

Comment: It has entire xml which I want, when I xml_print($dom); I can see it. If I had that problem I would have stated that. I am sorry, but your response is useless to me. Anyway, I have found the way around, still waiting for exact solution.

Comment: Ok Sorry for first reply. i think $dom->saveXML() will convert your Domobject to string. try it.So it will be force_download($name,$dom->saveXML() );